# Validation of views even though auto_reval is set to DEFERRED

Tags: db2

According to http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/r0054951.html?lang=en it should be possible to create stored procedures and views referencing not existing tables if the setting *AUTO_REVAL* is set to *DEFERRED*.

On my system however the following commands (creating a view referencing an invalid table) still result in an error:

- db2 get database configuration | grep REVAL

> Auto-Revalidation                          (AUTO_REVAL) = DEFERRED

- db2 "create view v1 as select * from not_existing_table"

> DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
>   valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
>   SQL0204N  "DB2ADMIN.NOT_EXISTING_TABLE" is an undefined name.  SQLSTATE=42704

DB2 does not create the view, also not as an invalid object.

Am I missing anything? Are there other options I need to verify? I'm using DB2 LUW 10.5 (fixpack 4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `DEFERRED` setting only affects `CREATE OR REPLACE` statements. If you want simple `CREATE`s to behave in this manner, set `AUTO_REVAL` to `DEFERRED_FORCE`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply: I justed tested it and after setting the setting AUTO_REVAL to DEFERRED_FORCE I was able to create my view.